# Problema com Seletor ID em CSS

Tags: html, css

**Meu problema é o seguinte,** tenho um arquivo `css`, nele há 2 tipos de formulário, um para contato e outro para outro tipo de contato, porém as `forms` entram em conflito fazendo que uma fique desconfigurada e a outra normal. Fiz uma pesquisa rápida sobre como poderia arrumar isso, descobri os Seletores ID do CSS, porém ao aplicar isso ao meu `css` e meu `html` ele ficou completamente bugado.

**Eu já** referenciei o ID no arquivo `html` e referenciei as tags no `css` porém nada muda, continua bugado.
Bom, o código `css` está assim:

```
 @media(XXXX){
 form > div {XXXX}
 .col-submit {display: block;}

 .col-2 {XXXX}
 .col-3 {XXXX}
 .col-31 {XXXX}
 .col-4 {XXXX}
 .col-5 {XXXX}

 .col-submit button {XXXX}
 }

 form {XXXX}

 form > div > label {XXXX}
 form > div.switch > label {XXXX}

 form > div > .col-4 {XXX}

 label > input {XXXX}
```

E o `html` assim:

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
    <form onsubmit="return false">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>
                Nome
                <input placeholder="Nome Inteiro" id="name" name="name" tabindex="1">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>
                Empresa
                <input placeholder="Nome da Empresa" id="company" name="company" tabindex="2">
            </label>
        </div>
        [..]
        <div class="col-submit">
            <button class="btn btn-submit">Enviar Mensagem</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Eu preciso apenas que o `form` entre no seletor, o resto não tem problema.

**Resumindo,** preciso do `css` mudando esse `form` desse jeito e outro `form` do outro jeito.

**Para quem ainda não entendeu**, apenas preciso que esse `css` não mude as outras `form` do site.

### **Obs**

Resolvendo esse problema, a outra form do site vai se consertar sozinha.

Comment: No teu exemplo falta a tag de fecho de `<div class="map-wrapper">`. Isso existe no teu código?

Comment: Sim @Sergio, é que eu encurtei pra não ficar uma coisa cansativa, acabei cortando algumas partes mas nada de interessante

Comment: Ok. Podes criar um exemplo aqui ou no jsFiddle com o código "bugado"? No teu CSS não vejo nenhum ID...

Comment: Já foi solucionado com a resposta do @TobyMosque

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

atribua um `id` para o `form`, então passe a referenciar o mesmo pelo `ID` no `CSS`.

```css
form input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

form#vermelho input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

form#verde input {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

form#azul input {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<form id="vermelho">
  <label>
    Vermelho:
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
</form>

<form id="verde">  
  <label>
    Verde:
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
</form>

<form id="azul">
  <label>
    Azul:
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Deu certinho amigo, problema resolvido, obrigado @TobyMosque